# Capturing SSL Traffic from My iPhone and Decrypting it

Tags: tls, decryption, iphone

I'm using an application connecting to a server over HTTPS and HTTP , I already monitor the HTTP traffic, but the I want to see the HTTPS traffic and decrypt it. I use Kali Linux & Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

First we need to address the elephant in the room. Unless you have permission to test these systems or own the devices, applications, and systems you are *testing*, **this activity may be illegal**. Now, with that out of the way:

In order to decrypt SSL (HTTPS) traffic, you'll need to either have a copy of the server's private key **or** generate your own cert / private key and use it while MitM'ing the traffic. Note that the second option will result in cert errors for the client that he/she will need to [by default] accept in order to continue interacting with the site/application.

Your title says from your iPhone but your question says using Win7 and Kali. I'll stick with Kali for this answer because it's the easiest thing to get you started.

**One Approach with Kali**

By default, Kail comes installed with a web proxy known as [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_using.html). <-- That link will take you to setting Burp up to intercept SSL traffic. You can MitM traffic by configuring your browser to proxy through the localhost (usually on TCP/8080 by default). Then you can browse to the site (accept the SSL warning) and see your traffic decrypted in Burp.

**A More Complicated Approach** - *Will Work for Smartphones Too*

You'll need to generate a certificate and install it on your devices to be able to decrypt the traffic later. You then need to proxy the traffic through a device capable of doing the packet decryption/inspection. A better overview of the process can be found [here](http://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/wsm/xtm_11/en-us/content/en-us/certificates/cert_https_proxy_resign_c.html). That link is for a specific program/setup, but the process is pretty much the same no matter what the specific implementation is.

Comment: Apple Transport Security (ATS) is [on for apps since iOS 9.0](http://tinyurl.com/gu9y7t7) . ATS [verifies server certificates by default](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html). Intercepting a modern iOS app's HTTPS traffic with burp will result in a failed connection unless the author took steps to explicitly allow untrusted certificate authorities to ignore the CN of the cert -- unless you install burp's CA cert [manually](http://bit.ly/2c1uwne).

Comment: what i mean < i use the application on my i phone , and i want capture it by my PC i tried Burp Suite and it's can't get the https requests i running IOS 8 .

Comment: You'll need to install the portswigger (Burp Mftr) CA cert on your phone so that it can connect without SSL issues and then use your kali box as the gateway/proxy for your traffic.